# "in" keyword overwrites mock

Tags: python, mocking, python-3.5, python-unittest

I am mocking an enum so I can test my code independently of any real values, but the mock is obviously overwritten in the function I am testing if I use the "in" keyword. The mock is visible in the function I am testing and I don't really understand why this is happening.

Here is a short example to highlight my problem:

function.py:

```
from enum import Enum

class TestType(Enum):
    APPLE = 1

class CheckTheEnum():
    def get_enum_value(self, test_type):
        # "test" has a variable "TEST" here.
        test = TestType

        # this call always fails for the mock, but it works if I execute it for real.
        if test_type in TestType:
            return test_type.value
        else:
            raise NameError
```

test.py:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import patch

from function import CheckTheEnum

class TestCheckTheEnum(TestCase):
    @patch('converter.test.TestType')
    def test_get_enum_value(self, mock_testtype):
        mock_testtype.TEST = 10

        checker = CheckTheEnum()
        value = checker.get_enum_value(mock_testtype.TEST)

        self.assertEqual(value, 10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Why isn't mock_testtype.TEST found here?

Comment: Well of course that test returns False. You didn't configure the mock to return True for that test.

Comment: How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Note that after you mock it, your `TestType` object is not a `TestType` anymore but a `unittest.mock.MagicMock` one, so your `in` will fail.

You can add a `has_value` method in your **TestType** enum class:

```
class TestType(Enum):
    APPLE = 1

    @classmethod
    def has_value(cls, value):
        return any(value == item.value for item in cls)
```

Then change your `CheckTheEnum` class to:

```
class CheckTheEnum():
    def get_enum_value(self, test_type):
        # this call always fails for the mock, but it works if I execute it for real.
        value = TestType.has_value(test_type)
        if value:
            return value
        else:
            raise NameError
```

Finally, instead of mocking the Enum mock the `has_value` method:

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import patch

from function import CheckTheEnum

class TestCheckTheEnum(TestCase):
    @patch('converter.test.TestType.has_value', return_value=11)
    def test_get_enum_value(self, mock_testtype):

        checker = CheckTheEnum()
        value = checker.get_enum_value(mock_testtype.TEST)
        mock_testtype.assert_called_with(mock_testtype.TEST)

        self.assertEqual(value, 11)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And just vary what it will return.

Comment: Thank you, but I actually would like to understand why my sample doesn't work. The mock does have the TEST attribute, why isn't it returned?

Comment: Oh I see. @eega it is because your TestType is not a TestType object anymore when you pass it at the tests as a mock, it is a unittest.mock.MagicMock now. And your 'in" fails because you are looking at a TestType which now is unittest.mock.MagicMock. I updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, I see. Is there actually a way to add something like "in" to a mock?

Comment: I don't know @eega.